# cURL: HTTP file download

Tags: linux, curl

I have tried to download a file using `curl "https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf7e7vndqd9hv05/Ace_The_IELTS.pdf?dl=0" -o "file.pdf"` but it downloads a file which is of few bytes. When I open the link in the browser I see the web page opened with the pdf but not downloaded to my desktop. I guess that curl command is downloading the webpage but not exact pdf file. Can anyone please help me in downloading the file using curl. Am I missing anything? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox file links go to a webpage, that then redirects to the actual content.

The link to the above PDF is actually at

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/v0qPqJrCIS7IvTmXr0pXBFKnnbmZpsRfSNxDhfqcjLg88F7ErNCyNAaOIATPKrWT?dl=1
```

The easiest way I can think to determine the actual url is to first do:

```
curl "https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf7e7vndqd9hv05/Ace_The_IELTS.pdf?dl=1" -o "temp.txt"
```

(note the `dl=1`)

Then look at the `temp.txt`:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Found</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
    <p>The resource was found at <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/jGdZ7mfVMNV7VCiauE9T7kGpaOyBKyu6i8KaAzqLzUSaEd2ElXllzDeQEC8DCxHr?dl=1">https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/jGdZ7mfVMNV7VCiauE9T7kGpaOyBKyu6i8KaAzqLzUSaEd2ElXllzDeQEC8DCxHr?dl=1</a>;
you should be redirected automatically.

<!--  --></p>
    <hr noshade>
    <div align="right">WSGI Server</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you'll see the correct url.